# Sudo x chroot conflict in Ubuntu Core with Miniconda

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, tensorflow, archlinux

I'm running a Raspberry Pi on Ubuntu Core in snap classic and just installed Miniconda at chroot. I run the following commands to install Keras and Tensorflow:

```
export LC_ALL=C  
sudo chmod -R a+rX /home/rubenszmm/miniconda3     
sudo chown -R rubenszmm /home/rubenszmm/miniconda3  
conda install scikit-learn  

sudo apt-get install python3-numpy  
sudo apt-get install libblas-dev  
sudo apt-get install liblapack-dev  
sudo apt-get install python3-dev   
sudo apt-get install libatlas-base-dev  
sudo apt-get install gfortran  
sudo apt-get install python3-setuptools  
sudo apt-get install python3-scipy  
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install python3-h5py  

wget https://github.com/lhelontra/tensorflow-on-arm/releases/download/v1.8.0/tensorflow-1.8.0-cp35-none-linux_armv7l.whl
```

(classic)rubens@localhost:~/miniconda3$

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties

cp /home/rubens/tensorflow-1.8.0-cp35-none-linux_armv7l.whl tensorflow-1.8.0-cp35-none-linux_armv7l.whl  
easy_install pip==1.5.6 (8.1.1)  
pip install numpy==1.14.5  
sudo apt-get install python3-pip  
sudo pip3 install tensorflow-1.8.0-cp35-none-linux_armv7l.whl  

sudo pip3 install keras
```

Everything was successfully installed, but when I run:
    python3

The machine learning libraries were installed, but Keras and Tensorflow are not found.

When I run:

```
sudo python 3
```

The machine learning libraries are not there, but it's where Keras and Tensorflow were installed. I get the following error:

> ImportError: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.22' not found (required by /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so)

So far, this has been a hard job, given that Ubuntu Core runs on an ARM processor and has only the most basic libraries in its OS, missing even `wget`.

Any ideas on what I can do to solve this issue ?

**ADDED:**
Documentation of the project available at:

https://github.com/RubensZimbres/Repo-2018/tree/master/Raspberry%20Pi3%20IoT-Project

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem:

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common  
sudo apt-get install libstdc++6  
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test   
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get upgrade  
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

**ADDED**

The 'classic' environment of Ubuntu Core runs in chroot but you need sudo permission to run Python notebooks. `pip` and other Python libraries are installed in chroot, so, besides libraries dependencies, sometimes you need to run:

```
export LC_ALL=C
source .bashrc
```

To make sure libraries are properly installed via `pip`

Comment: How does this solve your original problem? Did you run these commands after which other commands you run? You should be more precise, even though you're answering a question to yourself, so that this answer can also be useful to other future readers.

Comment: Instead of providing a negative score for my answer (that indeed solved my problem and may help a lot of people in the future, given that Ubuntu Core documentation is poor), one should first understand how Ubuntu Core works and how libraries like Tensorflow are installed in a Raspberry Pi. Here's the full documentation about the solution: https://github.com/RubensZimbres/Repo-2018/tree/master/Raspberry%20Pi3%20IoT-Project